# Finding Super Digit using Javascript, NaN error in CMD

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to find the Super Digit of a number in JS.

A NaN error occurs when I use this length of number in my code 5678572322398989898999 but no error occurs when I use 567857232239898989899.

Note the first number has 22 characters while the second has 21 characters. I don't really understand why the character length should be an issue or is it my code

I am using node 10.11.0 and running the code in CMD

```
var number = 5678572322398989898991;
var total = number + '';

while(total.length > 1) {
  var temp = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < total.length; i++) {
     temp += +total[i];    
  }
  console.log(temp);
  total = temp + '';
  }    
console.log(total);
```

Replace both numbers and see the behavior...the one with 22 characters has a NaN error in CMD while the other has no error and displays the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one (`5678572322398989898999`) stringifies into scientific notation: `"5.67857232239899e+21"`. This leads to calculating `5 + (+".")`; but since `+"."` is `NaN`, the result is `NaN` (as almost always when one of the operands is `NaN`). This propagates to the final result.

The second one (`567857232239898989899`) stringifies to an integer-looking `"567857232239899000000"`; with no weird non-digits, `NaN` never appears. However, note that it exceeds `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` (`9007199254740991`), and thus loses precision, which will make your result likely not what you wanted.

You might solve it by starting from a string in the first place, or by using `BigInt` (big integers) - which you get by suffixing a number literal with `n` (`5678572322398989898999n`). Note that while big integers work in Node and Chrome, they're not available (yet) in almost any other JS implementation.

Comment: i have tried the first solution of using it as a string and it works...would you mind to show me how you implement BigInt in this particular case...because the solutions in MDN and other sites is still giving me some difficulty in the implementation

Comment: I did: use `5678572322398989898999n` instead of `5678572322398989898999`.